# Are editing limitations placed on the VLC for Unity Free Version?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vlc, libvlcsharp, vlc-unity

I want to stream a video from YouTube into a Unity application. This seems straightforward enough with the [VLC for Unity plugin](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/vlc-for-unity-windows-133979). I downloaded the free trial version from the [video labs website](https://videolabs.io/#unity), and tried to simply swap the URL of the `Media` object in the `minimalPlayback.cs` script to a YouTube video, but nothing plays. Is there something else I need to configure, or is it a limitation of the free version that it is designed to just *show* me what is possible without letting me use it in a different way. I'm guessing it is the latter, but I am hoping for some confirmation before buying the full version.

Comment: No. There are no limitations of the free one other than the amount of money you are allowed to make

Comment: That's incorrect, BugFinder.

Answer (score 1):

See the docs for YouTube support: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/blob/3.x/docs/how_do_I_do_X.md#how-do-i-play-a-youtube-video

```
Core.Initialize();

using(var libVLC = new LibVLC())
{
    var media = new Media(libVLC, "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ", FromType.FromLocation);
    await media.Parse(MediaParseOptions.ParseNetwork);
    using (var mp = new MediaPlayer(media.SubItems.First()))
    {
            var r = mp.Play();
            Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

> is it a limitation of the free version

Nope, the only limitation of the free version is that you have the [Videolabs](https://videolabs.io/) logo as a watermark on your frames. That and volunteer-based support.